# Printing UTF-8-encoded byte string

Tags: python, printing, utf-8, byte, character

I have a data of a form:
`v = "\xc5\x84"`

This is a byte representation of an utf-8 encoded character "ń".

How can I print >>ń<< using variable v?

I'm using python 2.7.2

In original the variable v contained string:

`v = "\\xc5\\x84"` (double backslashes)

vs

`v = "\xc5\x84"` (single backslashes)

which is by itself valid utf-8 character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit In my machine the output depends on the shell/python used, as shown below.
As commented by Klaus a major actor here would be the locale setting in your system.

```
>>> v = "\xc5\x84"

>>> print v   #in pycrust shell python 2.6
Å„
>>>

>>> print (v) #in idle python 3.2
Å
>>>
```

the machine has the following settings:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getlocale()
('es_ES', 'cp1252')
```

Independently of this setting, you get your character with

```
>>> print v.decode('utf-8')
ń
>>>
```

Comment: +1 This has the best chance of working. If the shell being used is the Command Prompt window (aka `cmd.exe`) in Windows, it won't work in locales like US and Western Europe (encoding is `cp437` or `cp850`), should work in a Central Europe locale with encoding `cp852'.

Answer (score -2):

Uhm, you don't need to do anything special... It's just `print v`?

```
>>> v = "\xc5\x84"
>>> print v
ń
```

Comment: Is the answer python interpreter dependent. B'coz when i did print v the output was `┼ä`. I am using python 2.6

Comment: I can not get correct printing directly neither in python 2.6 (pycrust) nor python 3.2 (idle). Could you comment on your answer?

Comment: @joaquin Maybe... I'm using python 2.7.2 just as the OP, but it also works for me in python 2.6. Might be related to the shell though? My locale is set to UTF-8 (`LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"`)

Comment: -1 `print v` (where `v` refers to a UTF-8-encoded string that's not all ASCII) works ONLY if `sys.stdout.encoding` is UTF-8 and it's not lying.

Comment: Not the shell, at least not that alone. I get a nice `ń` in 2.7, but 3.1.3 says `'Å\x84'` and the second byte is not printable.

Comment: @JohnMachin well, apparently that's how it is *out of the box* on my machine.

Comment: you are right probably is the locale settings. In my case  `locale.getlocale()` returns ('es_ES', 'cp1252'). I wanted to setlocale (to complete my answer) but I'm not familiar with the module and I could not get the way from the docs.

Comment: Kindly consider the possibility that not all machines are running the same OS and same version of Python and same shell.

Comment: @JohnMachin duly considered. I don't want to delete the answer since the comments contain information that might be useful to someone.