# Easiest way to enumerate utf-8 string

Tags: python, utf-8

I read a lot of links and suggestions and after all I'm even more confused then before when I need to manipulate strings in Python that ain't ASCII characters.

I use Python 2.7 on Ubuntu:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

for i, j in enumerate('Сон'): print '%d: %s' % (i+1, j)
```

output:

```
1: Ð
2: ¡
3: Ð
4: ¾
5: Ð
6: ½
```

What is the easiest way I get 3 UTF-8 encoded characters enumerated, instead 6 byte characters?

Comment: Does this link on SO answer your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873517/printing-utf-8-encoded-byte-string

Comment: Or if it's a variable not a literal, `utf8_string.decode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a 'u' in front of it to specify it is unicode:

```
for i, j in enumerate(u'Сон'): print '%d: %s' % (i+1, j)
```

Output

```
1: С
2: о
3: н
```

Comment: @theta, what does `sys.stdout.encoding` say?

Comment: I already tried this and now because I got two similar answer and checked more - the problem was my editor - SciTE and it's output pane. In terminal your suggestion works fine and in SciTE (were I work most) I get UnicodeDecodeError. Will investigate further

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer: [don't](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/).

```
>>> len(u'Сон')
3
```

Comment: I browsed it before - decode early, encode later. Didn't get it, and hope Python 3 comes sooner then expected

Comment: @theta Eh? Python 3.0 was released in December of 2008.

Comment: And does you favourite Python package support it yet, or your system set it as default interpreter :D

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to output the utf-8 characters, you'll also need to make sure Python knows which encoding to use

```
$ export PYTHONIOENCODING=ascii
$ python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'ascii'
>>> for i, j in enumerate(u'Сон'): print '%d: %s' % (i+1, j)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0421' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

---

```
$ export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
$ python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> for i, j in enumerate(u'Сон'): print '%d: %s' % (i+1, j)
... 
1: С
2: о
3: н
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem as mentioned was my editor. It output pane is probably ascii, although I set it to `output.code.page=65001` if you are familiar with SciTE

Answer (score 1):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
for i, j in enumerate(u'Сон'):
    print '%d: %s' % (i+1, j)
```

About source code encodings in Python: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

'u' prefix before string means that unicode string will be used.